# How to use subscribe for multiple reducers in redux (RFC)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use the data coming from two reducers on one page.
While using combine reducers.

**I am getting this error,**

```
Attempted import error: 'cartItemsReducer' is not exported from './cartItemsReducer'.

Attempted import error: 'getProductDetailsReducer' is not exported from './getProductDetailsReducer'.
```

I have two reducers,

**1. cartItemsReducer**

```
const initialState = {
    cartItems : ""
}
function cartItemsReducer(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "totalCartItems" : 
            return {
                cartItems: action.data.length
            }
        default : 
            return state;
    }
}
export default cartItemsReducer;
```

**2. getProductDetailsReducer**

```
const initialState = {
    data : []
}
function getProductDetailsReducer(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "bookClicked" : 
            return {
                data: action.data
            }
        default : 
            return state;
    }
}
export default getProductDetailsReducer;
```

**And one root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { getProductDetailsReducer } from "./getProductDetailsReducer";
import { cartItemsReducer } from "./cartItemsReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  getProductDetailsReducer,
  cartItemsReducer
});
```

**This is my store**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import combineReducers from "../reducer/rootReducer";

const store = createStore(combineReducers, applyMiddleware(logger));
export default store;
```

**This is how I am doing subscribe**

```
  store.subscribe(function () {
    console.log(store.getState().data);
    console.log(store.getState().cartItems);
  });
```

**This is how I am using connect**

```
export default connect()(CartPage);

export default connect()(ProductPage);
```

Comment: You are using `export default` for exporting the module. So while importing you should ditch the curly braces. Do it like `import cartItemsReducer from "./cartItemsReducer";`. Or you could remove the default from export and just export like `export cartItemsReducer;`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `react-redux`, you should not use `store.subscribe` or `store.getState` at all - that is done by using either `useSelector` (which is the preferred way, but only available if you are using function component) or `connect`.

With useSelector, that would look like

```js
function MyComponent(props){
  const somethingFromData = useSelector(state => state.data.something)
  const somethingFromCartItems = useSelector(state => state.cartItems.something)
}
```

As for your problem:
You are doing a *default export*, but a *named import*. Those are two different concepts. You would need to do
`import getProductDetailsReducer from "./getProductDetailsReducer";` - without the `{}`.

Generally, I think you might be following very outdated resources on Redux as modern Redux looks very different. Please follow the official Redux tutorial:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts